# VPS going down every sunday

Tags: linux, vps

My website is running on vps and keeps going down every sunday for an hour or so. Hosting provider says there is nothing wrong at his end.
Can anyone suggest what could be the possible problems and in which direction should i move further to find a fault.

Comment: Can you provide more information related to your problem? Kernel version, OS, logs, etc..? `/var/log/messages` could give you a clue.

Answer (score 6):

Whether you trust the hosting provider or not, there are some fairly easy ways to determine what is up in most cases.

First, look at the system log around the time it goes down and around the time it returns.  If you see (for example) that it is booting right before it goes up, but don't see a log that it shut down, power failed.  Look at what happened and draw inferences.

If that doesn't yield any results, make a cronjob that pings an outside host (google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 is awesome for this) and appends the results along with a timestamp (from `date`) to a log file.  Read the log file the following day and see if the pings succeeded, or if not, why they failed.  This will point to whether there was a routing issue, or a disconnected cable, or something like that.

While you are checking your logs, be sure to check for things like very expensive cronjobs being kicked off right around the time it goes down, or service restarts.

Comment: thanks falcon.. will look it into it as per your guidance